# How Get values of class and filter them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi. how i can get values of a class if that have multiple value ?**
for example i have this tags

```
<ul>
    <li id="145" class="AAA BBB">
    <li id="148" class="AAA BBB CCC">
</ul>
```

1. `class="AAA BBB"`
2. `class="AAA BBB CCC"`

every time that i click on this tag i need have last value of class attribute.
for example in above class (1) i need to (BBB) and in (2) i need to (CCC).
 how i can get them ?
I dont need that to have all of values .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.split()` by spaces and then use `.pop()`.Try this:

```
$(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cuDQ/)**

Answer (score 5):

In native JS:

```
var classNames = document.getElementById('145').className.split(/\s+/);
console.log(classNames[classNames.length - 1]) // 'BBB'
```

Or even shorter: (Suggestion by [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan))

```
var classNames = document.getElementById('145').className.split(/\s+/);
console.log(classNames.pop()) // 'BBB'
```

Of course you can make it a one-liner:

```
document.getElementById('145').className.split(/\s+/).pop()
```

[VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) suggested the use of `/\s+/` instead of `' '` as the `split`'s parameter, to catch multiple subsequent white-spaces, instead of just the single one.
However, you might want to trim off whitespaces after the classnames (Like `class="a b c "):

```
document.getElementById('145').className.trim().split(/\s+/).pop()
```

Comment: [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is native and can be chained :)

Comment: @Cerbrus That will be also good to use `/\s+/` regex for split in case class names are delimited with many spaces or new lines.

Comment: @VisioN: I like the suggestion, results in cleaner classname arrays. Even though technically, it doesn't matter how many empty strings the array contains, since you just need the last element.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ha, indeed! Haven't thought about that. However, if the class name has trailing spaces the approach won't work.